# Does anyone know the name of this UIObject? (Picture inside)

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to add something like this to my program but idk what it's called.
[image]

I'm talking about the buttons that pop up "Photo Library" "Take Photo or Video" "Cancel"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a `UIAlertController` with style `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet`.
You use it like this:

```
UIAlertController *aC = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                            message:@"Message"
                                                     preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

[aC addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Button 1"
                                       // Style can be default, destructive or cancel
                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                     handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    // handler
}]];

// Add more actions (buttons) here if needed

// Assuming you're in your view controller,
// present the alert view controller like this:
[self presentViewController:aC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

UIActionSheet class from Cocoa touch.

Comment: Thank you! I went with the other answer though because his was more complete but I appreciate it! :)